# SSH key or user restricted to only making a SOCKS proxy

Tags: ssh, authentication, ssh-tunnel, socks-proxy

I like making an SSH tunnel that acts as a SOCKS proxy with a command like:

`ssh -i ~/.ssh/some_key -N -D 8000 someuser@remote.server.com`

This allows me to set up local programs like `curl` to hit resources in `remote.server.com`'s private network:

`curl --proxy socks5h://localhost:8000 192.168.10.10:9000`

Can I make `~/.ssh/some_key` a special kind of key that *only* has permissions to create this SOCKS proxy tunnel but cannot log in or do anything else? Alternatively, can I make `someuser` a special kind of user that *only* accepts SSH SOCKS tunnel connections, but not other SSH connections?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The OpenSSH `ssh` client can do two types of forwarding, through the `-L` and `-D` options. These two types of forwarding work differently in the client, but they use the same SSH protocol features and the same SSH server features. In other words, they "look" the same to the SSH server.

You can configure the server restrict a session to port forwarding, but you can't specifically limit them to port forwarding via SOCKS. The server doesn't specifically know that a particular forwarding request is associated with SOCKS.

You enable an SSH key by placing the public portion of the key in an [*authorized_keys*](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd#AUTHORIZED_KEYS_FILE_FORMAT) file on the SSH server. You can add directives to each key which control how the key can be used.

It looks like the directives *restrict,port-forwarding* should accomplish what you want. You may also need to add the directive *command="/bin/false"* to prevent the user from running commands. There is also a *permitopen* directive which limits what ports a user can forward to, but that's not likely to be useful with SOCKS-based port forwarding.

The relevant line of the _authorized_keys_ file would end up looking like this:

```
restrict,port-forwarding,command="/bin/false" ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1...
```

Comment: This works for my purposes! In case somebody else finds this, this is a useful answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/48129/how-to-create-a-restricted-ssh-user-for-port-forwarding and the authorized_keys directives are enumerated here: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/en/man8/sshd.8.html